# Getting output which is not expected while formatting Date from string

Tags: swift, nsdateformatter

The snippet is

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/DD/YY"
var String = "12/19/16"
print(dateFormatter.date(from: String)!)
```

the output that i'm getting is : **2016-12-18 18:30:00 +0000**

Can anyone predict why this is happening? and also help me finding the solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to check 24 hours format also. Once you check this, it will give you expected output...

Comment: Your date format is just *wrong.* Please do lookup the documentation or similar questions.

Comment: what output or response you want ??

Comment: post your code and output instead of an image.

Comment: @NiravD: I have re-added the [swift] tag. [swift3] is useful as an *additional* tag but should not be the only tag. There is a good chance that the code remains valid in Swift 4 or 5 and people search for it just with [swift].

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for this info, next time will follow this instruction.

Comment: I have put that image to show the code along with the output. Common guys. What makes you trouble here ?

Comment: @MartinR Really the [swift3] tag isn't relevant here – quoting the tag wiki "*Use this tag only for questions directly related to changes in version 3 of Apple's Swift programming language*". This question isn't about a Swift 3 change, it's just about `NSDateFormatter`.

Comment: @RamcharanReddy The reason behind down vote of your question is, you need to put relevant code(as Text) not image of code. You can use image to show some extra details. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is `dd` not `DD` and `yy` not `YY`, so change you `dateFormat` to `MM/dd/yy`.

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yy"
print(dateFormatter.date(from: dateString))
```